# <li> is aligned at bottom of <ul>

Tags: css

Guys i have problem with `<li>`. I need it to be top aligned, and it's bottom aligned.

Here is the HTML code. Please have a look at `li Product 2` - i need it to be shown at the top of the `ul`, not bottom.

```
<ul class="produt-details">
<li class="produt-details-label">Product 1</li>
<li class="produt-details-info">option 1a, option 1b</li>
</ul>
<ul class="produt-details">
<li class="produt-details-label">Product 2</li>
<li class="produt-details-info">option 2a, option 2b, option 2c, option 2d, option 2e, option 2f, option 2h</li>
</ul>
<ul class="produt-details">
<li class="produt-details-label">Product 3</li>
<li class="produt-details-info">option 3a, option 3b, option 3c</li>
</ul>
```

Here is CSS:

```
li.produt-details-label {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    width: 21%;
li.produt-details-info {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-left: 4em;
    width: 60%;
```

Here is the screen shot:
[product 2 li problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1k8E.png)

UPDATE:
Problem solved by partypete25. Thanks you guys!

Comment: What if you use a `table` to display your items instead of a list?

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top` to li.produt-details-label

```
li.produt-details-label {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    width: 21%; 
    vertical-align:top 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dz59dLwm/